The party was so dull that I might just as well have stayed home

The party was so dull that I might just as well have stayed home.


The party was so dull that I should have stayed home.

The party was so dull that it might have been good that I stayed home.

My hypothetical staying home would have been just as well bored as the party was bored.


What is more close to the meaning of the example sentence?
★Note that 1 includes the "will" of the speaker, whereas 2 includes the 'guess'
Endit note:

was added.


Neither 1 nor 2 expresses the meaning you describe. I suggest 3. The party was so dull that I would not have been less bored if I had stayed at home.

I added 3. What about no. 3?

No 3 is meaningless.

You are bored by something that is boring.  To bore is a transitive verb.  Parties bore you.  Movies bore you. Staying at home bores you.

I'd paraphrase "just as well" as "equally", "with the same effect".
